# Merge tag [nc] into [netcat]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The tags [nc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nc) and [netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netcat) are being used for the same purpose. As [netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netcat) has ten times as many questions, a more substantial tag wiki, and is fully spelled-out (vs. an abbreviation), I recommend that it be kept as the main tag and that [nc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nc) be merged into it.

Comment: I removed the tag from a couple of R questions that were not related to netcat. Can someone go through the list of questions tagged 'nc' and verify that all of those remaining are relevant to netcat? After that I can do a merge.

Comment: I looked through the whole list and removed the 'nc' tag from a question about 'netcdf'. I don't see any other misuses.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll go ahead and proceed with the merge.